# Java code containing ! In for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

How does ! big in the for loop affects the program.Is there any checking done between i and big?

```
public int numberOfMoves(int size) {

    int power=2;
    int[] moves = new int[105];
    int pocet = 0;
    boolean big=false;
    for (int i=1;i<105&&!big;i++) {
        int num=1;
        for (int j=0;j<power;j++) num*=i;
        if (num>size) big=true; else {
            moves[pocet]=num;
            pocet++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ! flips the boolean !(true) == false.

Comment: But how does it affect for loop functioning .after check I<105 what happens next it makes boolean to be true and then increments .Can this thing be done inside body loop? Change the code structure  without changing its functioning

Answer (score 2):

! is a negation operator, this means that `!true == false` and `!false == true`.   In this case, the outer loop condition is "Loop while `i<105` and `big is false`"

Answer (score 0):

the ! operator is checking to see whether `big is false`. So as long `big is false` it will run.